# Bug ao usar comando cin detro de um loop

Tags: c, c++

Quando executo esse código ele *buga*, eu digito 1 e ele entra na função cadastro mas não *pausa* para ler os dados(fica imprimindo coisas sem parar)quando eu troco o `cin` por `scanf` ele funciona). Tem como fazer ele funcionar com o comando cin?

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #include<string.h>
            #include<iostream>
            using namespace std;

            typedef struct {
                char nome[100];

            }pessoa;
            pessoa a[100];
            int c=0;

            void cadastro();
            void imprimi();

            void cadastro(){
                std::cout<<"Digite o nome:"<<endl;
                cin.get(a[c].nome,100);
                c++;
            }



            void imprimi(){
            cout<<"\n\n\n";
                for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
                    std::cout<<"Nome:"<<a[i].nome<<endl;
                    std::cout<<"------------"<<endl;

                }
            }

            main(){
            int op=0;
                while(op!=3){
                    std::cout<<"\n\t---IMC---"<<endl;
                    std::cout<<"1-Cadastrar usuario:"<<endl;
                    std::cout<<"2-Listar usuarios:"<<endl;
                    scanf("%d",&op);

                    fflush(stdin);
                switch(op){
                    case 1:
                        cadastro();
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        imprimi();
                    break;
                    case 3:
                        exit(1);
                    break;
                    default:
                        std::cout<<"digite um numero valido"<<endl;
                    break;

                }

            }


            }
```

Comment: Primeira coisa: pra que misturar código C com C++? Eu não sei nem se dá vontade em mexer em um código tudo misturado.

Comment: Olá, Matheus. Seja bem-vindo. Você tem comportamento indefinido na primeira linha da função cadastro (`fflush(stdin)`). Não sei quem te ensinou isso, mas tá errado. Seu código está realmente muito grande e bagunçado. Por favor, crie um [mcve] que exiba o problema.

Comment: Testei seu programa. Entrei com os dados no formato que o cin espera, usei ponto ao invés de vírgula. Funcionou. Depois testei de novo e quando entrei a altura usando vírgula o resultado foi o comportamento que você falou. É complicado usar cin para ler dados porque você não tem controle sobre o que o usuário vai digitar e dependendo da entrada não dá pra prever o comportamento. Faz tempo que não escrevo programas de linha de comando em c/c++, mas se fosse fazer usaria cin.getline pra ter certeza que li toda a linha, depois algo pra converter a string pro formato que quero, sscanf é uma opção.

Comment: reduzi o codigo(ainda reproduz o mesmo problema),tentei cin.getline e n mudou nada(quando uso scanf ele funciona).tem como fazer funciona usando cin?

Comment: aqui quando testo com cin ele n para pra receber os valores

Comment: Qual compilador você tá usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para funcionar basta colocar `cin.ignore()` antes do `cin.get(a[c].nome,100)`. Isto porque quando vc escolhe a opção 1 você aperta ENTER e o cin apanha esse ENTER, então você ao fazer `cin.ignore()` você estará a "ignorar" esse ENTER.

```
        #include<stdio.h>
        #include<stdlib.h>
        #include<string.h>
        #include<iostream>
        using namespace std;

        typedef struct {
            char nome[100];

        }pessoa;
        pessoa a[100];
        int c=0;

        void cadastro();
        void imprimi();

        void cadastro(){
            std::cout<<"Digite o nome:"<<endl;
            cin.ignore();
            cin.get(a[c].nome,100);
            c++;
        }



        void imprimi(){
        cout<<"\n\n\n";
            for(int i=0;i<c;i++){
                std::cout<<"Nome:"<<a[i].nome<<endl;
                std::cout<<"------------"<<endl;

            }
        }

        main(){
        int op=0;
            while(op!=3){
                std::cout<<"\n\t---IMC---"<<endl;
                std::cout<<"1-Cadastrar usuario:"<<endl;
                std::cout<<"2-Listar usuarios:"<<endl;
                scanf("%d",&op);

                fflush(stdin);
            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    cadastro();
                break;
                case 2:
                    imprimi();
                break;
                case 3:
                    exit(1);
                break;
                default:
                    std::cout<<"digite um numero valido"<<endl;
                break;

            }

        }


        }
```

Comment: vlw cara,testei aqui e funcionou perfeitamente